# Unable to find XPath for mouse hover

Tags: xpath

I can't find my XPath so that I can't run the code. Can anyone solve this issue?

I have to do mouse hover manage content then click on content Library:

```
package TestNG;

import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeTest;

public class MuviOTT {

    public WebDriver driver;
    static WebElement element;
    //@Test
    public void FreeTrail() throws Exception {
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@type='submit']")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.id("name")).sendKeys("subhankar jena");
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        // driver.findElement(By.id("companyname")).sendKeys("itworld");
        driver.findElement(By.name("phone")).sendKeys("7684914257");
        driver.findElement(By.id("email")).sendKeys("xyz143@gmail.com");
        driver.findElement(By.id("inputPassword")).sendKeys("Bbsr@2021");
        // driver.findElement(By.id("subdomain")).sendKeys("iddomain");
        driver.findElement(By.id("terms_check")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.id("nextbtn")).click();
    }
    @Test
    public void f() {
        
    }

    @BeforeTest
    public void openURL() throws Exception{
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "F:\\Library\\chromedriver.exe");
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
        // Opening the Browser and Entering the URL
        driver.get("https://www.muvi.com/");
        // Maximize the Browser window
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        //driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(2, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        driver.findElement(By.id("load_login")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.id("LoginForm_email")).sendKeys("subhankarjena14@gmail.com");
        driver.findElement(By.id("LoginForm_password")).sendKeys("Gulu@123");
        driver.findElement(By.id("btn-login")).click();

        Actions action = new Actions(driver);
        // Mouse Hover actions on an element using Action Class:
        action.moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//em[@class='icon-film left-icon']"))).perform();
        
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
        element= wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("//a[contains(.,'Content Library')]")));
        
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(text(),'Content Library')]")).click();

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It might be the case that the exact locator is not found. As when you mouse over > then the element appears, and it would be disappearing if you are moving out. Pausing or debugging will help to find out the locator.

You can try this:

1. Hover over the element by using Action class:

   Actions action = new Actions(driver);
   action.moveToElement(we).build().perform();
2. Use the Debugger in the Network of your browser(after clicking F12)
3. Move to the element mentioned in the step one and right click on the 3 dots(see picture below) and click > break on subtree modification
4. This will pause you execution whenever there is a change in the DOM i.e in case of Mouse over.

[image]

5. Then you can use the arrow keys to navigate to the hidden elements of the DOM

[image]